# Convert tuple to variant

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17

I have the following type

```
using MyTuple=std::tuple<std::vector<char>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<int>>;
```

How to write a meta function that convert MyTuple to the following type?

```
std::variant<std::monostate,char,double,int>
```

Comment: Did you try to write something? What are you stuck on?

Comment: It does not make sense how one would convert such a `tuple` into such a `variant`. Since any or all of those `vector`s may have data, it's not clear what the contents of the `variant` would be. And if they have multiple elements, how would the equivalent `variant` store that?

Comment: @NicolBolas OP did ask about a *meta* function for type computation

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

template <typename Tuple>
struct get_variant;

template <typename... Ts>
struct get_variant<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<std::monostate, typename Ts::value_type ...>;
};


using MyTuple = std::tuple<std::vector<char>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<int>>;
using MyVariant = typename get_variant<MyTuple>::type;

using Expected = std::variant<std::monostate,char,double,int>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Expected, MyVariant>);
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb2cc6f3ec1b914b)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function declaration (no definition required), a bit of template machinery and `decltype` to do that.
As an example, this is a solution that doesn't stuck on the exact number of vectors (but you can easily force it if you want):

```
template<typename... T>
std::variant<std::monostate, T...>
f(std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>);

template<typename T>
using to_variant = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));
```

Here is a minimal, working example:

```
#include<tuple>
#include<variant>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename... T>
std::variant<std::monostate, T...>
f(std::tuple<std::vector<T>...>);

template<typename T>
using to_variant = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));

using MyTuple = std::tuple<std::vector<char>,std::vector<double>,std::vector<int>>;

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<
        to_variant<MyTuple>,
        std::variant<std::monostate,char,double,int>
    >);
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wr7IkdYWzRkwdeHp).